# Receiving exit code (1) when trying to manipulate strings from codewars assignment? How can I do it differently and avoid Index Errors?

Tags: python, string, split

I have been working on this codewars assignment the entire day, but I keep failing the test on code wars. Running into index errors and exit code (1) even though I am passing every test and attempt, the exit code seems so illusive yet confusing. I understand if my program doesn't do what it is supposed to but it is passing the tests, and right now there are some errors I don't quite understand messing up my program in ways that I can't even comprehend. Because they are returning the strings exactly as requested by the assignment, so why... is it not working? What have I done wrong? Please help me almighty code wizards, I am a noob...

Working on Split Strings: *Complete the solution so that it splits the string into pairs of two characters. If the string contains an odd number of characters then it should replace the missing second character of the final pair with an underscore ('_').*

Here is my Code:

```
def solution(string):
    join_string = "-".join(string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(string), 2))
    x_string = join_string.split("-")
    underscore = "_"
    index = (len(string) - len(x_string))
    if index % 2 == 0:
      for i in range(0, index):
        return x_string
        break
      else:
        x_string[index] = x_string[index] + underscore
        return x_string 
    elif index > 2:
        x_string[index] = x_string[index] + underscore
        return x_string
    elif index < 1:
        x_string = []
        return x_string
```

The error comes up at

```
x_string[index] = x_string[index] + underscore
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: you can avoid index errors by checking it the list even has that index, i.e. if the index is smaller than the length of the list or using `try/except`

Comment: The error (IndexError) is telling you that x_string is less than index characters long. There are quite lot of issues with your code that could cause that, to the point that its unclear what you intended each line of code to do. Are you able to add a comment to most lines explaining what you wanted it to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
join_string = "-".join(string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(string), 2))
```

already does the entire job you want, except for the underscore at the end if there were an odd number of characters in the input. Your code is making very heavy weather of this special case. Check if the input string has an odd number of characters:

```
if len(string) % 2 == 1:
```

and if it has, append an underscore to the returned value:

```
join_string += "_"
```

Your question doesn't say what the expected output is, and it's hard to tell from the code, so, to keep to the essential point, the whole function becomes

```
def solution(string):
    join_string = "-".join(string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(string), 2))
    if len(string) % 2 == 1:
        join_string += "_"
    return join_string
```

I get the output

```
>>> solution("123465")
'12-34-65'
>>> solution("1234657")
'12-34-65-7_'
>>> solution("1")
'1_'
>>> solution("")
''
```

If instead you want, say, a list of 2-strings, then do

```
return join_string.split("-")
```

Comment: If the task is to "split the string", surely the solution should return a list?